# How do I get content from an element: after it's in a div with Selenium?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I'm having trouble listing the contents of a compoment: after my test. I'm writing a test and need to get the text from a combobox, but this combo is a `div` in one element:

Example: It has a combo in a `/div` and has an element `:after` where it is like other options of this combo, when I click on the combo, opens another `/div` with like other options of combo selection. I write this snippet of code, but not right.

```
List <WebElement> records = driver.findElement (By.xpath (".// div"))
.findElements (By.xpath (/ div));
```

How can I work with this type of element?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on StackOverflow should be written in the English language, sorry.

Comment: Maybe more suited for https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Once you clean up the question and add some details, we can get it reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to get the Pseudo-Element property: content

```
public String getPseudoAfterContent(WebElement target) {
    String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':after').getPropertyValue('content');";
    return ((JavaScriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, target);
}

WebElement divEle = driver.findElement(xxxx)

getPseudoAfterContent(divEle);
```